# How can I render all objects behind a plane with a specific transparency value?

Tags: rendering, transparency

I have a game where there a multiple floor levels between the player switches. The floor is not present everywhere, so you can look through it. When 'working' (playing, building stuff, etc.) on a specific floor I want to add a transparency value to everything that is NOT on the current floor.
Ho can I accomplish that, and what is the best/most efficient way to do that?

[image: sketch of the scene]

Answer (score 2):

Draw the floor (transparent part) after drawing the rest of the objects with transparency blending turned on.

Otherwise you can pass a currentFloor uniform to the fragment shader and a floor attribute to the objects so you can add the extra shade conditionally.

Comment: Needed to read that multiples times to understand that :) (I am just doing it as a hobby for a month ...)

So the **first solution** is to **apply a transparent blending shader to the transparent part of the floor**, right?

Can you explain the _second solution_ more detailed? I don't know what all of it means, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Order of rendering is important.

You need to draw the objects in order, draw objects far away first. Using alpha values ofc, for an example alpha = 0.5.

Think this is called back to fron rendering.

So if you stand at X, floor is |, object are 1,2,4...

X | 1 2 3 4

Then you render 4, 3, 2, 1 and finally the floor |.